# A-Frame buffer-geometry-merger seems to shift entities in some cases

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe

I have a simple case of a A-Frame scene using the [buffer-geometry-merger component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-geometry-merger-component), which seems to work well when writing entities in static HTML, but not when the same entities are injected in the DOM by building a A-Frame component: in this case, the geometry seems to be shifted, as if the position of the parent were applied (again) to the merged entity, even when its position is (0,0,0) with respect to its parent.

The HTML file is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-geometry-merger-component/dist/aframe-geometry-merger-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cubes-buffer-min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene renderer="colorManagement: true;" stats>

      <a-box position="-5 0 -3"></a-box>
      <a-box position="-10 0 -3"></a-box>

      <a-entity test position="-5 0 0">
      </a-entity>

      <a-entity position="-5 0 3">
        <a-entity buffer-geometry-merger>
          <a-entity geometry="primitive: box" position="0 0 0"></a-entity>
        </a-entity>
      </a-entity>

      <a-entity camera position="0 15 0" rotation="-90 0 0"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript file defining the `test` A-Frame component (included from the above HTML file) is:

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('test', {

  init: function () {
    let base = document.createElement('a-entity');
    base.addEventListener('loaded', (e) => {
      base.setAttribute('buffer-geometry-merger', {});
    });
//    setTimeout(function() {
//      base.setAttribute('buffer-geometry-merger', {});
//    }, 2000);
    let box = document.createElement('a-entity');
    box.setAttribute('geometry', {buffer: true, primitive: 'box'});
    box.setAttribute('position', {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0});
    base.appendChild(box);
    this.el.appendChild(base);
  },
});
```

When loaded in the browser, you can see how the "static" box appears where it is expected, in (-5,0,3), but the dynamic one (the one injected by the `test` component) appears shifted to the left, in (-10,0,0). The first two boxes in (-10,0,-3) and (-5,0,-3) are just for reference.

I included the commented out timer code to illustrate what happens. If you disable the 'loaded' event listener, and uncoment the timer code, you can see how the dynamic box is located in the right place, but then the timer fires, and the `buffer-geometry-merger` is added, the box is "shifted" to the wrong place.

In this screenshot, white boxes are for reference, purple box is the dynamic one, blue box is the static one:

[image]

Any idea about what is happening, or how to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, in Your case:

```
// pseudo code, before the merge is done
<a-entity test position='-5 0 0'
   <a-entity base buffer-geometry-merger
       <a-entity box
```

1) The merger is creating a clone of the box using it's **world** matrix ([source](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/blob/master/components/geometry-merger/index.js#L57)).
2) Then it combines the geometries (here only the box) into a single mesh which is used as the *base* mesh ([source](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/blob/master/components/geometry-merger/index.js#L62-L64)).

But hey, the *base* already is shifted by `-5 0 0` due to its parent ! So actually, the world matrix is applied twice.

---

Why isn't it happening with a setup like this:

```
<a-entity position="1 1 -2"> 
   <a-entity buffer-geometry-merger>
     <a-entity geometry="buffer: true; primitive: box;'></a-entity>
   </a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

Quite identical, isn't it ? Apparently not, because here the merge is done before the parent transform is applied. You can verify this by logging (done on the entity with the merger component):

```
var worldPos = new THREE.Vector3();
worldPos.setFromMatrixPosition(this.el.object3D.matrixWorld);
console.log('not loaded', worldPos) // looks like the parent(s) transforms are ignored
base.addEventListener("loaded", e => {
   worldPos.setFromMatrixPosition(this.el.object3D.matrixWorld);
   console.log('loaded', worldPos) // this seems to give a proper value
});
```

The component is not waiting until the node is loaded - so in the "static" case it seems to work properly.

---

I don't think the component is supposed to work properly when the entity is being nested, or itself having nested entities. Most examples I found have simple layout:

```
<a-entity buffer-geometry-merger
   <a-box 
   <a-sphere
   .....
```

---

The simplest solution is to subtract the parents transform from the merged one.
In Your case:

```
// test component, after setting the merge component:
let mtx = new THREE.Matrix4()
mtx.getInverse(this.el.object3D.matrix)
base.object3D.applyMatrix(mtx)
```

Something just like [this](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stack-59110629?path=index.html:16:76).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I've been late in commenting because I was blown up by a code quite similar to yours, but hadn't time to investigate it. I've produced a simple modification that shows the issue now: using your code for the test component, just adding a new box within the static element makes the box in the dynamic element to "move". It seems like somehow the matrix being applied is not the one for the dynamic element, but the one for the last box drawn in the scene. Please have a look at the code: https://glitch.com/~acidic-alloy (the grey box is only for reference)

Answer (score 0):

I think I now fully understand what happens, plus I have a substitute for the [buffer-geometry-merger component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-geometry-merger-component) that works both with static and dynamic (JavaScript inserted) entities with BufferGeometry.

The problem, as @piotr-adam-milewski found out, is how matrixes for the different meshes are applied (or not). To make a long story short, I understood the issue when I learned that:

- The element in which the `buffer-geometry-merger` component is inserted has a mesh, `this.el.object3D`.
- All meshes for children of that element are arranged, once they are inserted in its subtree, as children of `this.el.object3D`. Each of these meshes has a property `parent`, referencing its parent in this arrangement.
- Each of these meshes has both `matrix` and `worldMatrix` properties. `matrix` is the relevant one here: it keeps the "extended position" (position, rotation, scale) of the mesh, relative to its parent. For the record, `worldMatrix` keeps the extended position absolute (relative to the scene).
- Each of these meshes has also a `geometry` property, with its geometry. Coordinates of this geometry are relative to its extended position.
- All of this mean that if we just copy (clone) the geometry of a mesh A, and insert it in its parent B (B is `A.parent`, it will be displaced, since the matrix of A is no longer applied. So, the correct way of "moving" it to its parent is to "bake" (apply) the A matrix into it:

```js
let geometry = A.geometry.clone();
geometry.applyMatrix(A.parent.matrix);
A.parent.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
```

- If we want to "copy" the geometry several levels up in the hierarchy of meshes, we should bake in to it (apply) the matrixes of each of the levels, except for the matrix of the last (topmost) mesh, since that matrix will be applied to the resulting geometry, because it will be attached to the same mesh.

So, the way of merging geometries in all components in a subtree is basicall to find all of them, bake in each of them (apply) their matrixes, and those up to (but not including) the root of the subtree, and them merge all of them together.

This is done by the following A-Frame component (which is a slight modification of [buffer-geometry-merger component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-geometry-merger-component):

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('buffer-geometry-merger', {
  schema: {
    preserveOriginal: {default: false}
  },

  init: function () {
    var geometries = [];
    let self = this;

    this.el.object3D.updateMatrixWorld();
    this.el.object3D.traverse(function (mesh) {
      if (mesh.type !== 'Mesh' || mesh.el === self.el) { return; }
      let geometry = mesh.geometry.clone();
      let currentMesh = mesh;
      while (currentMesh !== self.el.object3D) {
        geometry.applyMatrix(currentMesh.parent.matrix);
        currentMesh = currentMesh.parent;
      }
      geometries.push(geometry);
      mesh.parent.remove(mesh);
    });

    const geometry = THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries(geometries);
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
    this.el.setObject3D('mesh', this.mesh);
  }
});
```

With this, the case in the question seems to work as it should.

**Note:** I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/pull/249) to the original buffer-geometry-merger component now, intended to fix it following this answer.